# Show Parent category and Subcategory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to show sub category in below to the respective parent category in wordpress Sidebar.

Without using plugin I need to show the parent category and sits sub categories  in sidebar with following manner

```
Category1

     --Sub1

     --Sub2

Category2

   --Cat2Sub1

   --Cat2Sub2
```

Comment: what you mean display in WP widgets. please explain

Comment: I hope this link will help you. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-categories-and-subcategories-in-a-nested-list

Comment: https://vrajeshdave.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/list-categories-child-categories-grandchild-categories-post-titles/

Comment: Now my question is clear?

Comment: I need to use the wordpress code for this implememnation

Comment: Provided answer is not working on my end >any one please suggest better option

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this code

```
<?php
if(is_category()) {

    $breakpoint = 0;
    $thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
    $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );

    if(empty($subcategories) && $thiscat->parent != 0) {
        $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.$thiscat->parent.'' );
    }

    $items='';
    if(!empty($subcategories)) {
        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
            $items .= '
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->term_id.$current.'">
                <a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.' ('.$subcat->count.' posts)</a>
            </li>';
        }
        echo "<ul>$items</ul>";
    }
    unset($subcategories,$subcat,$thiscat,$items);
}
?>
```

Comment: I just tried with this code but it's not showing any result